# JSP login page session timeout

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, mybatis

I have created a login page for mock of hotel administrator. Now I want to add session time function to it. In other words, let's say the user leaves the computer (he is still logged into the admin webpage) for like 10 minutes or so. Then when he come back, I want to end the current session and then redirect to login page (this is more secured and his personal info would never be lost!).

How do I make that happen?

```
public class LoginServlet extends SpringInjectedServlet {
@Autowired
private LoginService loginService;


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");

    String error = null;

    //code for checking correct input
}

// mock
private boolean check(String id, String password) {
    return loginService.authenticate(id, password);
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("LoginServlet");
}
}
```

Comment: What does your current code for this look like?

Comment: I have a loginServlet using the doPost method.

Answer (score 6):

Use **Authentication Filters** to check for Session in **every request** like

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();
 if (session == null || session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
        // Forward the control to login.jsp if authentication fails or session expires
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request,
            response);
 }
```

This will check for login username from session for every request if its null or the session expired ,it will redirect to login page.

Add this in web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Check it [**here**](http://a4academics.com/blog/380-j2ee-user-authentication-using-java-servlet-filters).

Comment: request.getSession is missing parenthesis.

Comment: request.getSession() never returns null, use request.getSession(false);

Answer (score 1):

After you've verified the credentials, set a session variable for the userid, and to set the session expiration:

```
 session.setMaxInactiveInterval(600); //600 secs = 10 mins
 session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
```

Then at the top of all your JSPs and in all your servlets you do something like:

```
String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
if(userid==null)
{
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    return; //the return is important; forces redirect to go now
}
```

After the 10 minutes have elapsed, this will only redirect the user to the login page if they click a link, refresh, or somehow go to another page.  If they just leave the page sitting there open, it will still display.  To change that you would have to involve Javascript somehow.

Comment: Thanks for info. But how do I set Javascript? What kind of keywords should I type in google or any good example?

Comment: I think what you would do is set a cookie on the client side and have it also expire at the same time that the server session will expire (or a little after to be sure it will work). Then in Javascript have a timer that reads that cookie and sees if its expired yet, and sets url location when it does. Something along those lines. You can't have Ajax hitting the server to see if the session expired because that will count as activity and reset the timer of the server session's expiration making it not expire.

Comment: OK, but I am new to Javascript so it's hard to understand with all words. What does the code look like?

Comment: I don't have any example code for the Javascript. You should lookup how to get/set cookies in Javascript, and how to use the two timer methods setTimeout and setInterval.